# How to locate the elements which has same id and xpath

Tags: selenium, drop-down-menu, ide

In my form, all the option in the dropdown menu has same ID and xpath, I tried out giving value as well. While running the test, the menu button is clicked and list displayed (at this point test failed) but the value not fetched and returned. I got the error "UI active menu Item not found". Could anybody sort this out?
Select command and WaitForElementPresent in IDE didn't help.
Please find my Webdriver coding in Java:

```
    //clicked the list button
     driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_cphWMContent_eddlWH_list_button")).click();
    //to select the option
    new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/ul[2]"))).selectByVisibleText("Option1");
    //wait to return the selected   
    Thread.sleep(1000);
```

Comment: Add html of your dropdown. Explain how you get its values and how textbox is related to question

Comment: Please post the HTML of the dropdown and the code you are using to interact with the dropdown.

Comment: <tr>
 <td>click</td>
 <td>id=ctl00_cphWarehouseMasterContent_eddlSupplier_list_button</td>
 <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>click</td>
 <td>id=ui-active-menuitem</td>
 <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>click</td>
 <td>id=ctl00_cphWarehouseMasterContent_eddlWarehouse_list_button</td>
 <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>click</td>
 <td>id=ui-active-menuitem</td>
 <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>click</td>
 <td>id=ctl00_cphWarehouseMasterContent_eddlItem_list_button</td>
 <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>click</td>
 <td>id=ui-active-menuitem</td>
 <td></td>
</tr>

Comment: When I run the testcase, I got [error] Element id=ui-active-menuitem not found in, <td>click</td> <td>id=ui-active-menuitem</td> <td></td> </tr> <tr> <td>click</td>. Also, selenium stuck on, at the point when the list is displayed and its not selecting the value from the menu and the list remains open in the screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

xpath is not a finite nor definitive property. There is not one xpath for an object, so you statement that your elements have the same xpath is both right and wrong!

All buttons have the same xpath (//button) but all buttons have many other xpath some which will be unique.

Also, elements which have same
 HTML ID are actually displaying invalid HTML as w3c says all HTML IDs must be unique.  So if you do have duplicate ids, then raise a bug as the HTML is invalid.

Comment: Thank you Robbie Wareham

Comment: @Kavr If you feel it is the answer, then please accept